# Guest connected to the internet through the host in Virtualbox host-only network

Tags: virtualbox, internet

I have a host-only network in virtualbox. The guest is Windows and the host is ubuntu. Is it possible with this configuration to connect the guest to the internet via the host? So that all the traffic is sent first to the host that then sends it outside?

Answer (score 0):

you would have to make your host to receive the packages and send it further. That can be done by:

1. installing a Proxy Server on it
2. making it a router that simple forwards IP packages
3. making it a router that does NAT